# Como pegar próximo código de uma tabela no pgsql?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, pdo

No MySQL utilizo a sintaxe

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'NOME_DATABELA'
```

Como capturo a informção no Postgres?

Comment: Como assim "próximo código"?

Comment: Não sei o que você quer dizer com "próximo código" mas talvez você encontre o que procura consultando o [Information Schema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) ou os [Catálogos do sistema](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html). Caso esteja se referindo a um campo do tipo auto-increment então veja as funções de manipulação de sequences: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi o que você quis dizer com "próximo código" mas enfim.
Você pode tentar informações da table, como faz com o SHOW TABLE STATUS no MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables;
```

Ou ainda informações do banco se for o caso:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity where datname = 'SEU_BANCO';
```